# WordPress Page Template changes back to Default Template on Update

Tags: php, wordpress

I've created a WordPress template for a page. The template is called koebenhavn.php. It's located in a subdirectory in my themes directory. The code looks like this:

```
<?php
/*
Template Name: Koebenhavn
*/
?>

<?php get_header(); ?>

<?php
    query_posts('cat=3');
    while (have_posts()) : the_post();
    the_content();
    endwhile;
?>

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

When I go to the Admin-panel and choose the page, which I want to use this template on, and I press the blue "Update"-button, it switches back to "Default Template" automatically. I've never experienced this before.

I've tried adding the template on already existing pages as well as newly created pages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason for this behaviour was caused by the name of the file. I was using the Danish letter, ø, in the filename `københavn.php`.

There's probably a way to work around this, but for the easy way out, just write `koebenhavn.php` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Just to be clear, you are going to an existing page AND selecting the template before hitting update?  I see nothing wrong with the code itself outside of some extraneous tagging, none of which relates to your problem but I'll paste the cleaned up code below.

I would suspect this is a file permission problem since it is visible in one sense (wordpress can read it) but not in another (wordpress cannot seem to 'execute' it).

Alternatively, there could be a problem within the database, other plugins, and so on.  Generally it's a good practice to disable all plugins and test to see if the anomaly repeats itself despite that.

```
<?php
/*
Template Name: Koebenhavn
*/

get_header();

    query_posts('cat=3');
    while (have_posts()) : the_post();
    the_content();
    endwhile;

get_footer();
?>
```